# I can't to show Jquery dialog of Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem when I want to display a jquery dialog according to a condition. I do not know if they influence the fact that in one of them an ajax request is made since when printing by console.log it shows me that the values of the condition are indeed fulfilled. I think you will understand better by seeing what I am doing.

My code en HTMl basically is a button with differents values in text():

```
<td><a rel="<?php echo md5($row['id'].'p');?>" class="class1 sp btn btn-warning"><i class="fa <?php echo $icon;?> "> <?php echo $status;?></i></a></td>
```

Then, i create the event on click for the button as follow:

```
$('a.class1').click(function(e){

                var status=$(this).text();
                console.log(status);
                if(status==='X'){
                    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                      "Si": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $.ajax({

                        })
                        .done(function(data) {

                           if (data==1){

                               $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                                    modal: true,
                                    buttons: {
                                      Ok: function() {
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                      }
                                    }
                                  });
                           }else{
                            $('#msj_error').css("background-color","#7A0C0C").html('<h4 style="color:#fff;">Error recibiendo datos</h4>').fadeIn('fast').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');

                           } 
                        })
                        .fail(function(msg) {
                            alert("Fallo Conexion!!! \n"+msg);
                            //$("#Cargando").fadeOut("fast");
                        });

                      },
                      "No": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      }
                    }
                });
                }else{

                    $( "#dialog-message2" ).dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                          Ok: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                          }
                        }
                      });

                }
            });
```

However, the second message is shown regardless of whether or not the condition is met, and the status is 'X' when I print it on the console, what should I do?

Comment: You should confirm that `<?php echo $status;?>` returns 'X' and you should also try to trim the variable status in your javascript with `status.trim()` in case there is an extra space before or after it in the html. Just a heads up, you have class attributes twice in your `<a>`. Try and resolve that

Comment: The error of including the class attribute in the a tag was an error when editing to display it in the (EDIT) question. I will try with the trim

Comment: The trim function worked for me. Good suggestion, thank you.